# Why are the fitting results of the Arima() and glm() function different?

Tags: r, time-series, glm, arima, mle

I am confused about the difference in the fitting results of the `Arima()` function and `glm()` function.

I want to fit an AR(1) model with an exogeneous variable. Here is the equation:

```
$$
x_{t} = \alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}x_{t-1} + \beta_{1}z_{t} + \epsilon_{t}
$$
```

Now I estimate this model using the `Arima()` function and `glm()` function and compare the results, but the results turned out to be quite different!

Here is the sample data. x denotes the time-series variable, and z denotes the exogeneous variable, as shown in the equation above.

```
library(forecast)
library(tidyverse)
data("Nile")
df <- 
  Nile %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x)) %>% 
  mutate(z = rnorm(100))
```

Then fit the model using the `Arima()` and `glm()` and compare the results.

```
fit_arima <- Arima(df$x, order = c(1, 0, 0), include.mean = TRUE, xreg = df$z)
tibble(Parameters = c("x lag", "intercept", "z"),
       Coefficients = coef(fit_arima),
       Standard_Errors = sqrt(diag(vcov(fit_arima))))  
fit_glm <- glm(df$x ~ lag(df$x) + df$z) 
tibble(Parameters = c("intercept", "x lag", "z"),
       Coefficients = coef(fit_glm),
       Standard_Errors = summary(fit_glm)$coefficients[, "Std. Error"])
```

The results are displayed as follows.

`Arima()` function:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Parameters Coefficients Standard_Errors
  <chr>             <dbl>           <dbl>
1 x lag             0.510          0.0868
2 intercept       920.            29.4   
3 z                 5.02          12.1
```

`glm()` function:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Parameters Coefficients Standard_Errors
  <chr>             <dbl>           <dbl>
1 intercept       444.            83.4   
2 x lag             0.516          0.0896
3 z                 8.95          13.9
```

The estimated coefficient and standard error of x lag are quite close, but the values of other two variables are very different. I find this puzzling because both the `Arima()` and `glm()` function use the maximum likelihood estimator. Could you please explain why this difference happens and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `Arima()` does not fit the model given in your equation. It fits a regression with ARIMA errors like this:

```
x_{t} = \alpha_{0} + \beta_{1}z_{t} + \eta_{t}
```

where

```
\eta_t = \phi_{1}\eta_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}.
```

We can rearrange this to give

```
x_{t} = (1-\phi_{1})\alpha_{0} + \phi_{1}x_{t-1} + \beta_{1}z_{t} - \beta_{1}\phi_{1}z_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t}
```

This explains the major differences in the two results.

But even if you specified exactly the same model, they would give slightly different results because `Arima()` uses the true likelihood whereas `glm()` will use a conditional likelihood because of the initial missing value due to the `lag()` function.

See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/ for a discussion of the different model specifications.